# Calculation of QCRB from QCRB

Tags: quantum-fisher-information, quantum-metrology

On page 3 of  [Zhuang et al. (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07630), they found the quantum Cramér-Rao bound (QCRB) of the parameter using the quantum fisher information matrix. See Equations  $(15)$ and Eq $(16)$.

The problem is that I can't see how they find  the matrix from equation $(14)$ from the matrix from equation $(10)$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please do not post screenshots of text, rather use MathJax. Also please provide details what you were able to do on your own.

Comment: All they did was calculate $M_i$ using (11), but they did it for a specific state in (13) that you did not list in this question - that is the crucial detail (i.e., 14 is only true for a specific state)

Comment: Thank you , even with using the specific state (13) I can't found the same results as (14)  I have problems in summation

Comment: @SamoYass if you could write what you've tried and where you're stuck it will help someone help you here